# Images not displaying on GitHub Pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages

Images are not displaying on GitHub pages, but are displayed when viewing locally. I've tried multiple solution from here like using relative paths and lowercase for the files  and folders only, but it doesn't seem to be working. images using "src" are displayed as broken images while images using "url" are not displayed  at all. I've also set my "baseurl" in my "_config.yml" to my site's name.

Comment: See the How to Ask [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am using images in my github pages as well and it works perfectly fine. Please add more details to get your issue solved.